# base64 decode image in gif

Tags: php, base64, gif

Faced with such a problem, I can not convert base64 gif string to gif file and save it to disk, with base64 strings getting get its MIME types - application / octet-stream (video streaming), insert the following code (below) and get this error - " imagecreatefromstring (): Data is not in a recognized format in ", I do not know what to do.

```
    $img = base64_decode($photo);
    $f = finfo_open();
    $mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $img, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if($mime_type !== ImageHelper::MIME_TYPE_PNG
        && $mime_type !== ImageHelper::MIME_TYPE_JPEG
        && $mime_type !== ImageHelper::MIME_TYPE_STREAM) {
        throw new HttpException(400);
    }

    if($mime_type == ImageHelper::MIME_TYPE_STREAM) { // image gif
        $name = ImageHelper::generateImageName() . '.gif';
        $path = $prefixPath . $name;
        $img_handler = imagecreatefromstring($img);
        if($img_handler !== false) {
            imagegif($img_handler, $path);
            imagedestroy($img_handler);
        } else {
            throw new HttpException(400);
        }
    }
```

example string 
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhuQBpANQdASAgQEIgQCBOQEJYQIk/QCCAQFqMQGDAQICYQMuLQIvCQMDWQCAggEsggCBJgE1ZgEpgwIJfgmCNgGDAgFyCwIWNg...

Update:
Interestingly, this question when I convert gif file, I get the format 'application / octet-stream', rather than 'image / gif' why? I can not find the answer ...

Comment: Are you removing `data:image/gif;base64,` from the start of the string before feeding it into `base64_decode()` ?

Comment: @Scuzzy It's strange, when I work with the formats jpeg png I did not delete this line, it should be removed?

Comment: Yes, you could try... `base64_decode(end(explode(',',$photo))` (I'm sure there's a better strrpos/substr way but I'm feeling lazy)

Comment: @Scuzzy there are no errors, but the animation does not work, only the first frame appeared and nothing moves. (

Comment: @Scuzzy I need to maintain a dynamic gif. I think this is unrealistic))

Comment: What is the purpose of the image functions here anyway? It appears you're loading the gif and then printing it without any image processing?

Comment: @Scuzzy I have a moving gif, I have to pour it on a server that when inserted in the article, he also moved